# .NET Word add-in does not run on first execution

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, add-in, word-addins

I am writing an add-in for Word.  The add-in generally work correctly and has no significant issues.  The problem I have is that when I fix a bug and give a new build to users, the first time they run the add-in it behaves like the previous version of the add-in before the bug was fixed.  Subsequent executions exhibit the corrected behavior.

My users are using a Visual Studio installer and the add-in is not GAC'd.  I have verified that users are uninstalling the old add-in before installing the new one.

Does anyone know what might be responsible for this execution lag?

Comment: How do you deploy your add-in?

Comment: We deploy by way of WIX installer.  The installer copies the assemblies into our Program Files directory.  The assemblies are not GAC'd.

Comment: Before going more into details: Did you make sure that no instance of Word has been running (check in Task Manager, there might not be a window visible) while you installed the update?